# Cannot unmount external HDD. Only "force unmount" works

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, mount

I cannot use the Finder on my external HDD icon -> unmount. It doesn't work, only force unmount.

I think if I force it, some files can be damaged.

I have closed all programs running on it. With `sudo lsof|grep ExternalHddName` I wanted to find out the processes using this HDD. Nothing was shown.

**1. Should I avoid force unmount every time?** In meaning of whether id dangerous.

*Update*

`sudo lsof|grep /Volumes/ExternalHddName` should be used instead.

If I use `diskutil unmount /Volumes/ExternalHddName` I become `failed to unmount: dissented by PID=199 (/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw`

Im using the online game on the external HDD. Maybe this `socketfilterw` has something to do with it. But its active even 20 minutes after I have exit this game.

I have used `sudo kill 199`, after it unmount was possible.

**2. Should I every time I want to unmount this external HDD manually find which process use it and than manually kill this process?** I would like to do it in one step and without logout from Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Some online games have "helper apps" that update the game in the background. Try plugging in the drive and then unmount it **without** running the game. If it does work, then you could make a simple Automator/bash script to unmount the drive (it should consist of the two commands you mentioned above, except that you should use `sudo killall <appname>` for killing the process locking the drive.

Comment: Without the game was started I can unmount this HDD.

Comment: Should I write `sudo killall nameOfTheGame`? Could you show the complete script you mean please?

Comment: If I force unmount - can I become some problems for my HDD? Not for unsaved text files etc.

Comment: @MikroDel yes, 'killall nameofthegame' should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable firewall? From your post looks like it is a firewall process.

Comment: Could you expand your answer with *how* to disable the firewall?